# Partition still encrypted with luks after wipefs

Tags: partition, encryption, luks

I wiped the disk using

```
wipefs -a /dev/sda.
```

I happily formatted the disk, and it seems that when I'm about to mount */dev/sda3* it says **"unknown file system type crypto_LUKS"**.

I did no encryption on this partition, so it's like the previous configuration is saved somehow.
If I apparently wiped or reset the disk, how can this be possible?

Do I have to open and decrypt and remove encryption on that drive first?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`wipefs -a /dev/sdx` only wipes magic signatures on that device, not on its partitions. So at best, it only wipes your partition table, but if you then proceed to re-create the partitions at the same offsets at before, the old data is still there. You'd have to wipe the partitions as well.

```
wipefs -a /dev/sdx[1-9]* # wipe old partitions
wipefs -a /dev/sdx       # wipe the disk itself
parted /dev/sdx          # create new partitions
wipefs -a /dev/sdx[1-9]* # wipe the new partitions, just in case
# create filesystems or whatever
```

That aside it's also entirely possible for `wipefs` to not wipe something if it doesn't know the signature. Or for another program to still recognize the data on the partition despite the signature being damaged. `wipefs` only overwrites a few magic bytes, which is reversible in most cases.

Comment: Speaking of reversibility, there's a `--backup` option which helps with it.

Answer (score -1):

Use the much more simple wipe command:

```
cat /dev/zero > /dev/sda
```

But BE CAREFULL, all files are history after that.

Comment: I don't get it. Why is that after removing partitions and reseting a partition scheme the information is still there on the background like invisible? I could not even use wipefs cause apparently there was something still existing encrypted.
I thought simply removing partitions or doing "o" in gdisk or fdisk wiped everything as well.ç

Comment: I don't why `wipefs` does not work. The command above or `dd` if you like will work. `gdisk` or `fdisk`  does not erase the data area at all as they just re-organize the partition table.

Comment: @hschou, your command will work indeed, but it will take an "eternity" to run. **wipefs** takes only a couple of seconds, not hours or days.