# How to erase gpt partition table and how to make old partition forget mount information

Tags: linux, ext4, mkfs, e2fsprogs

We have Beaglbone black based custom board with 256MB RAM and 4GB eMMC.

We have script to flash software on the board.
Script erases gpt partition table using following commands

```
#Delete primary gpt (first 17KiB)
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/mmcblk0 bs=1024 count=17
#Delete secondary gpt (last 17KiB)
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/mmcblk0 seek=3735535 bs=1024 count=17
```

Partitions gets deleted however script re-partitions eMMC again in the same number of partitions.
After that it tries to format each partition using  `mkfs.ext4` (e2fsprogs version 1.42.13).

Now while formatting a partition `mkfs.ext4` complains that partition has filesystem on it and it was mounted at particular date in past and ask if it should proceed ?

```
/dev/mmcblk0p15 contains a ext4 file system labelled 'rootfs'
        last mounted on /mnt/rfs_src on Fri Feb 16 13:52:18 2018
Proceed anyway? (y,n)
```

This was not happening in past i.e. with e2fsprog version `1.42.8`
same script used to work.

From release note of `e2fsprog-1.42.13` I see that  `last mounted` is added to some structure.

Now question is how can we remove this `last mounted` information from partition?

I tried `wipfs -a` but it has the same behavior.
One way to zero while eMMC, however that will take lot of time.

Any suggestion/pointers ?

Comment: Does this help? https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/394999/30851

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, that perfectly worked for me. I was trying `wipefs -a /dev/mmcblk0` with `wipfs -a /dev/mmcblk0p[0-9]*` worked fine. That did what we wanted.

Comment: @frostschutz can you add that as answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @frostschutz, his suggestion worked for.
Just for completeness I am adding that as an answer,

Using following commands did the trick for me.

```
wipefs -a /dev/mmcblk0p[0-9]*
wipefs -a /dev/mmcblk0
```

First command deleted filesystem information from each partitions.
second command deleted partition table.

Answer (score 2):

From [mkfs.ext4](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mke2fs.8.html)'s man page:

> ```
>    -F     Force mke2fs to create a filesystem, even if the specified
>           device is not a partition on a block special device, or if
>           other parameters do not make sense.  In order to force mke2fs
>           to create a filesystem even if the filesystem appears to be in
>           use or is mounted (a truly dangerous thing to do), this option
>           must be specified twice.
> ```

you can just add the `-F` option to `mkfs.ext4` in the script to bypass the question and have it continue unattended. It's not clear from the description that this is the "or if other parameters do not make sense" case. I double checked that only a single `-F` is needed, thus still protecting against accidentally formatting a mounted filesystem.

I don't think the last-mounted-directory is related to this. It's just more failsafe added. Likewise, some newer versions of the interactive fdisk or gdisk do the opposite: when they detect a previous filesystem was there when creating a new partition, they offer to wipe the signature.

Comment: Thank you for reply A.B. I referred seen `-F` option however I don't want to use that because from the same help snippet I see that  "force mke2fs to create a filesystem" `even if the specified device is not a partition on a block special device, or if other parameters do not make sense`, I `mkfs` to error out when parameters do not make sense. Suggested answer from @frostschutz  worked for me is `wipefs -a` on each partition to delete ext4 filesystem. And then running it on main eMMC partition to delete partition table. i.e. `wipefs -a /dev/mmcblk0p[0-9]*` followed by `wipefs -a /dev/mmcblk0`