# Parted, cannot mount newly created partitions

Tags: linux, parted

I am making my own script for partitioning disks and I am unable to mount the partitions which were just created using parted CLI tool.

I am doing this on a virtual machine with virtual disks, but this should not matter as far as I know.

I execute:

```
parted -s ${device} mklabel gpt
parted -s ${device} mkpart primary ${fileSystem} ${start} ${end}
```

Variables in my testing scenario were

```
device=/dev/sdb
fileSystem=ext4
start=1
end=5000
```

Virtual disk is 10gb in size, so my scenario should create a 5gb partition, and it does if I use `fdisk -l` to list disks, but when I try to mount the newly created partition I get this:

```
wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error
```

Edit: I was not using mkfs the right way, I got it working now.

Comment: parted only sets partition type, but does not mkfs

Comment: I tried executing mkfs after parted, but this only works for the first time. I do execute the wipefs command before doing parted and mkfs stuff to ensure there is no partition table or partitions on the disk, but mkfs for some reason detects the previous filesystem and asks for a user input, which I cannot have in a script

Comment: maybe this? https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/394999/30851