# wipefs + disk not cleaned

Tags: linux, filesystems, rhel, ext4, lsblk

we erased the disk signature as the following  ( this is after we performed umount )

```
 wipefs -a /dev/sde
/dev/sde: 2 bytes were erased at offset 0x00000438 (ext4): 53 ef
```

then we check that disk is without file system as the following

```
lsblk -f

sde                ext4              20eba791-c9c9-4462-aa23-74c40a41b8a0
```

but in spite we erase the filesystem , lsblk still show the ext4 filesystem on sde disk

Comment: can't reproduce it / works for me, what happens when you re-run wipefs, and which version of lsblk are you using? but this behavior is also not entirely unexpected - wipefs only deletes very little (in this case, only 2 magic bytes are cleared) so it's not like the filesystem is gone entirely. see also https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/394999/30851

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the man page of `wipefs` (emphasis mine):

> DESCRIPTION
>
> wipefs  can erase filesystem, raid or partition-table **signatures** (magic strings) from the specified device **to make the signatures invisible for libblkid.**   wipefs **does not erase the filesystem itself** nor any other data from the device.

So, the only thing it guarantees is that after `wipefs`, the `blkid` command (or anything else that uses `libblkid` for identifying contents of block devices) will no longer detect that filesystem, RAID set, or partition table.

`lsblk` does use `libblkid`, but apparently that is not its *only* way to detect filesystems.